# Количество записей, возвращенных функцией db_query

Tags: php, drupal

Пишу свой первый модуль для Drupal 7. Подскажите пожалуйста, api функцию которой можно определить количество вернувшихся записей из api функции `db_query`. То есть по типу php `mysql_num_rows()`. Просьба `SELECT COUNT(*)...` не предлагать. считаю это неправильным способом... это лишний запрос в СУБД.

Comment: rowCount()
смотреть оф. документацию надо было внимательнее))

Answer (score 1):

db_query(...)->rowCount()